# Terminal command repeated twice to work

Tags: command-line, mysql, vmware

I am very new with linux and ubuntu. Installed it in VMWare Player yesterday and I've been watching some good command tutorials.

I've installed mysql and php and some stuff.

I've created a database and a table and been trying to play around a bit with the command and such. Now I noticed that I must enter a command twice to it to work, the first time I use it, it triggers an error. (This is only in the mysql area)

Check this out:

First i tried:

```
mysql> \G use my_database
ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Then I tried it again:

```
-> \G use my_database
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Why is this happening? Is it a bug? Or are there some reasons for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the reason to use `\G` in front of your command/query?!? Used like this, it is normal to get this error: `No query specified`, because you didn't specified any query before to use `\G`:

```
mysql> help
...
ego       (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.
...
```

The right way to switch to `my_database` from command-lie is:

```
mysql> use my_database;
```

or (see `help` again):

```
mysql> \u my_database
```

Also, when you switch to another database, I don't see any reason to use `\G`, since the output will be the same. but if you really want it, you can use after you typed your command/query, like this:

```
mysql> use my_database \G
```